# Actionscript 2 Instance name oftside of object

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

**How i can use instance name outside of current object?I want to make when this object hit object with instance name - level1 to trace Hit**

```
onClipEvent(load){
    var gravity = 9.8;
    var velocity = 0;
    var fps = 24;
}
onClipEvent(enterFrame){
    if (this.hitTest(level1)){
    trace("Hit");
    } else {

    }
    velocity = velocity+1/fps;
    this._y += velocity*5;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use "_root" as a parent... just like you have declared for your enter frame function.

Try changing the hitTest line to this:

```
if (this.hitTest(_root.level1)){
```